# QLabel expands when added to QScrollArea

Tags: qt

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setPixmap("x.jpg");
ui->scrollArea->resize(300,300);
label->resize(250,250);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(label);
```

when I do this, the size of label becomes 298, 298.
I want size of label to be 250, 250.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the default size policy is `QSizePolicy::Preferred`
So you may be noticing the label size changed.

try changing the size policy to fixed.

```
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum